# Как открыть доступ к новой папке в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый вечер эксперты =)

Имеется код в .htaccess в корне WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Я создал дополнительную папку на сервере с блогом WP. Дело в том что WP не даёт обратиться к скриптам в новой папке domen.ru/papka/cod.php, а выводит надпись что ничего не найдено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас правило составлено таким образом, что проблем не должно возникнуть. Т.е. если 
файл или директория существуют физически, то перенаправления на морду не будет. Указывайте в ссылке абсолютный путь до файла/директории:

```
<a href="/абсолютный/путь/к_новой_директории">GO!</a>
```